# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset on reaching 3000 users in JMeteR

Tags: jmeter, python-requests

All required changes have been done to respective files like:

- stalecheck=true,
- keepalive is checked from HTTP request defaults,
- retrycount=1,
- hc.parameters file changes,
- Socket timeout is 240000

Still we see "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" in response data however I see the valid requests been passed to Server.

The issue wasnt till we reach 3000 users, worked smoothly till 3000 users.

Comment: If answer is ok you should accept it and upvote.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Connection Reset has a lot of meaning, possible reasons are:

- One of the server components is not able to handle load so it closes connections on its side
- On JMeter side, check that you running in NON GUI mode and that neither JMeter JVM nor injector machine are overloaded which could explain this. See:

  - https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui

Comment: we are using non-gui mode only and load generator is not overloaded

Comment: how do we come to know at server's end if its closing connections